# Matching end of file with ansible lineinfile

Tags: ansible, regex, rsyslog, sed

I'm trying to replicate the following sed snippet in ansible's lineinfile module.

```
sed -i '/# The named pipe \/dev\/xconsole/,$d' /etc/rsyslog.conf
```

I know that I can template the file or brute force match the lines but I'd like to learn how to do the sed trick of matching to end of file with ansible. I am also aware the matching blindly to the end of the file isn't great practice either.

This was lifted from this blog post: https://blog.dantup.com/2016/04/removing-rsyslog-spam-on-raspberry-pi-raspbian-jessie/

The aim is to fix this error in rsyslog:

```
raspberrypi rsyslogd-2007: action 'action 17' suspended, next retry is Sat Apr  2 01:24:21 2016 [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
```

This error is caused by section at the end the config file /etc/rsyslog.conf

```
# The named pipe /dev/xconsole is for the `xconsole' utility.  To use it,
# you must invoke `xconsole' with the `-file' option:
# 
#    $ xconsole -file /dev/xconsole [...]
#
# NOTE: adjust the list below, or you'll go crazy if you have a reasonably
#      busy site..
#
daemon.*;mail.*;\
    news.err;\
    *.=debug;*.=info;\
    *.=notice;*.=warn   |/dev/xconsole
```

Comment: There's a solution for exactly same task on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38510313/2795592

Comment: Excellent thanks, solves the problem without templating as I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Your `sed` command truncates a file, whereas the `lineinfile` module "will search a file for a line, and ensure that it is present or absent. This is primarily useful when you want to change a single line in a file only" (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html).

`copy` or `template` still sounds like the best alternative here.

If you want to play around with `lineinfile`, your ssh server configuration is usually a good start.

Comment: Fair point, I'm comfortable with lineinfile and the various tricks you can pull with it, there is a concept of EOF in the module but not the same delete to EOF.